# What does "dR" mean when R is a matrix?

Tags: calculus, integration, lie-groups

I was trying to derive the Lie algebra $so(3)$ from the corresponding Lie group $SO(3)$. But an intermediate step stopped me. Belows are my derivation process:

1. Specify the identity of SO(3): identity matrix $I$.
2. Specify the inversion of SO(3):
   $$ R^T \circ R = R \circ R^T = I \Rightarrow R^{-1} = R^T$$
3. Time-differentiate the inversion:
   $$\dot{R}R^T =-(\dot{R}R^T)^T \Rightarrow \dot{R}R^T = [\omega]_x$$
   for some skew-symmetric matrix.
4. Add the time dimension:
   $$\dot{R}(t)R^T(t) = [\omega]_x(t)$$
   By definition, the exponential map $exp$ is just a kind of projection, hence $[\omega]_x(t)$ is constant with regards to $t$. Therefore, we get:
   \begin{equation} 
   \label{eq:1}
   \frac{dR}{dt} R^{-1} = [\omega]_x \Rightarrow dR \ R^{-1} = [\omega]_x \ dt 
   \end{equation}
5. Solve the ordinary differential equation(ODE) using Separation of Variables, which is just doing integration on both sides.

My question is:

1. What does it mean $dR$ when $R$ is a matrix?
2. How to solve the equation specified in 4. when the matrix multiplication is not commutative? I.e. Simply put integration sign on both sides:
   $$\int dR \ R^{-1} = \int [\omega]_x \ dt$$
   However, as far as I'm concerned, this form does not make any sense provided the matrix multiplication is not commutative.

Comment: In (2) you have not explicitly used that the matrices in $SO(3)$ are orthogonal. So (2) should read $(2')\quad  R^T.R=I$. 
In (3) you have to consider a curve in $SO(3)$ which starts at $I$ with velocity $X\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Then you get from $(2')$: $X^T.I+I.X=0$ or in other words the velocity vector $X$ of the curve is skew-symmetric, hence $\mathfrak{so}(3)=\{X\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}\colon X \mathrm{ skew-symmetric}\}$

Comment: I've updated my description. But I think you didn't get my point. My concern is how to solve the ordinary differential equation.

Comment: If $R=(r_{ij})$ is a matrix, then $\dfrac{dR}{dt}$ is $\left(\dfrac{dr_{ij}}{dt}\right)$. So $dR$ is just $(dr_{ij})$.

Comment: @TonyK So it's still a matrix, the infinitesimal R?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: At the top you said that you want to calculate $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. Since the Lie algebra is the tangent space of the manifold $SO(3)$ at the identity you only need to calculate derivatives. Solving the ODE would get you back onto the manifold $SO(3)$ - I guess you'd actually calculate explicitly what the exponential map of $SO(3)$ does. Are you familiar with the definition of a tangent space of a manifold in terms of velocity vectors of curves?
To 1. $dR$ is the infinitesimal displacement on $SO(3)$ and corresponds to the velocity vector.
To 2. What does the notation $[\omega]_x$ mean?

Comment: @Sven: "What does the notation $[\omega]_x$ mean?" I was wondering the same thing, but I didn't want to show my ignorance :-)

Comment: @SvenPistre Yes, I actually want to calculate the exponential map. But I don't know how to solve the ODE. $[\omega]_x$ is the skew-symmetric matrix related to the $\omega$ vector. The subscript $x$ is just a sign denoting the skew-symmetric operator, not to be confused with the $x$ variable.

Comment: It is still unclear to me what the “skew-symmetric matrix related to the $\omega$ vector” is. Maybe the answer that I posted clears things up for you a little bit?

Comment: @SvenPistre A symmetric matrix has the property $R = R^T$, while a skew-symmetric matrix $R = -R^T$. Substituting R with $\dot{R}R^T$ get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$Let me extend my comment a bit further.

The Lie algebra of a Lie group $G$ can be identified with the tangent space $T_eG$ at the identity $e\in G$.
The Lie group $SO(n)$ is the set of orthogonal $(n\times n)$-matrices of positive determinant and it is an open subgroup of the Lie group $O(n)$. Therefore, the tangent space at the identity of $SO(n)$ is equal to the tangent space of $O(n)$ which we shall compute.

Consider the smooth map $\Phi\colon GL(n) \to \R^{n\times n}, R\mapsto R^TR$.
Then $O(n)$ is exactly the level set $\Phi^{-1}(I_n)$ and the tangent space $\mathfrak{o}(n)=T_{I_n}O(n)$ is the kernel of the differential $d\Phi_{I_n}\colon T_{I_n}GL(n) \to T_{I_n}\R^{n\times n}$, i.e. you have to solve the linear equation $d\Phi_{I_n}(X)=0$ for $X\in T_{I_n}GL(n)=\R^{n\times n}$.

One way to calculate the differential $d\Phi_{I_n}$ is as follows.
Consider a curve $\gamma\colon (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to GL(n)$ *on the manifold $GL(n)$* which starts at the identity $\gamma(0)=I_n\in O(n)$ with velocity vector $\gamma^\prime(0)=X\in\R^{n\times n}$. In general you would let $\gamma(t)=\exp^G(tX)$ but here you can just take $\gamma(t)=I_n+tX$ (at least for $\epsilon$ small enough).
Now you can consider the composition $\Phi\circ \gamma\colon \R\to\R^{n\times n}$ - so that you can use your knowledge from calculus.
Then
$$d\Phi_{I_n}(X)
=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \Phi\circ \gamma(t) 
=\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} \big(I_n+tX\big)^T\big(I_n+tX\big)=X^T+X.$$
You immediately see that the kernel (and hence $\mathfrak{o}(n)$) is given by the skew-symmetric matrices.

---

In regards to your second question about how to calculate the exponential map:
The exponential map $\exp^G\colon \mathfrak{g}\to G$ provides a way to go back from Lie algebra onto the Lie group. One way to define it is by considering the ODE $$\gamma^\prime(t)=X_{\gamma(t)}, \gamma(0)=e$$
for an element $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ ( considered now as a left-invariant vector field on $G$). This ODE has a unique solution because the right-hand side $X$ is a smooth vector field.
Now define $\exp^G\colon \mathfrak{g}\to G$ by $$\exp^G(X)=\gamma(1)$$ where $\gamma$ is the solution to the above ODE.

For matrix groups $G$ (as in your case) the exponential map is just the regular exponential map of matrices $X\in \mathfrak{g}$:
$$\exp(tX)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}(tX)^k = I_n + tX+ \frac12 t^2X^2+\ldots$$
Note that the exponential map does (in general) not exhibit all the properties of the exponential map for real numbers, see e.g. [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)